# autocomplete suggestion is partly hidden in the editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using monaco for creating an expression one line input, here is how the autocomplete suggestion looks like
[image]

How can I configure the suggestion box to float above the editor, and not be partly hidden?
note: I do not want to increase the height of the editor - it is a one line editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the autocomplete suggestion pop out of the editor

[image]
The reason the autocomplete popup was hidden was since I used the [ember-monaco](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-monaco) package which wraps the monaco component with Iframe 
I had to use monaco-editor package directly using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112076/integrate-monaco-editor-into-ember-octane)

Comment: Can you explain what you did to pop it out of the editor? The answer you linked seems to answer an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The div holding the suggestions is a child of the top level monaco host and hence cannot show outside, without affecting the scrolling behavior of the editor.